# Page cannot be null error custom MOSS 2007 Webpart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I'm trying to write a webpart that basically pulls data from a list and displays it to the user. There is a feature news list where one of the columns holds a URL to an image. The web part should get the 3 most recent feature news items and create three image controls on the page. These image controls can be scrolled through by clicking on the buttons 1,2,3. (Ie, clicking on 2 will set the Visible property of image 1 and image 3 to false).

I have managed to implement AJAX here, but am now trying to use the UpdatePanelAnimationExtender from the AJAX Control Toolkit.

I have followed all instructions on how to use the toolkit, add it to the GAC, add a safe assembly, etc, and have gotten past all the errors besides this one:

"Page cannot be null. Please ensure that this operation is being performed in the context of an ASP.NET request"

My complete code below:

```
    using System; using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.Extensions; 
using Microsoft.SharePoint; 
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using AjaxControlToolkit;

namespace FeatureNewsWebpartFeature {
    [Guid("7ad4b959-d494-4e85-b164-4e4231692b8b")]
    public class FeatureNewsWebPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        private bool _error = false;
        private string _listName = null;
        private string _imageColumn = null;
        Image image1;
        Image image2;
        Image image3;
        UpdatePanelAnimationExtender upAnimator;


        [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [System.ComponentModel.Category("List Connection Settings")]
        [WebDisplayName("List Name")]
        [WebDescription("Enter the name of the news list")]
        public string ListName
        {
            get
            {
                if (_listName == null)
                {
                    _listName = "News";
                }
                return _listName;
            }
            set { _listName = value; }
        }

        [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [System.ComponentModel.Category("List Connection Settings")]
        [WebDisplayName("Image Column Name")]
        [WebDescription("Enter the column name of the ArtfulBits Image Upload column")]
        public string ImageUrlColumn
        {
            get
            {
                if (_imageColumn == null)
                {
                    _imageColumn = "Feature Image";
                }
                return _imageColumn;
            }
            set { _imageColumn = value; }
        }


        public FeatureNewsWebPart()
        {
            this.ExportMode = WebPartExportMode.All;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create all your controls here for rendering.
        /// Try to avoid using the RenderWebPart() method.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            if (!_error)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.CreateChildControls();



                    //Create script manager
                    if (ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page) == null)
                    {

                        ToolkitScriptManager scriptHandler = new ToolkitScriptManager();
                        scriptHandler.ID = "scriptHandler";
                        scriptHandler.EnablePartialRendering = true;
                        this.Controls.Add(scriptHandler);
                    }


                    //Create update panel
                    System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel imageUpdatePanel = new System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel();
                    imageUpdatePanel.ID = "imageUpdatePanel";
                    imageUpdatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
                    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id=\"updateContainer\">"));
                    this.Controls.Add(imageUpdatePanel);
                    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));




                    //Make SPSite object and retrieve the three most recent feature news items
                    SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList oList = web.Lists[ListName];
                        SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
                        oQuery.RowLimit = 3;
                        oQuery.Query = "<OrderBy>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='ContentType' />" +
                            "<Value Type='Choice'>Feature News Item</Value>" +
                            "</Eq>" +
                            "</Where>";


                        oQuery.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                            "<FieldRef Name='Feature_x0020_Image' />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Feature_x0020_Order' />");


                        image1 = new Image();
                        image2 = new Image();
                        image3 = new Image();

                        //For each item, extract image URL and assign to image object
                        SPListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(oQuery);
                        foreach (SPListItem oListItem in items)
                        {
                            string url = oListItem["Feature_x0020_Image"].ToString();
                            url = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("/Lists"));
                            url = url.Remove(url.IndexOf(";#"));

                            switch (oListItem["Feature_x0020_Order"].ToString())
                            {
                                case "1":
                                    image1.ImageUrl = url;
                                    break;
                                case "2":
                                    image2.ImageUrl = url;
                                    break;
                                case "3":
                                    image3.ImageUrl = url;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    //ERROR
                                    break;
                            }
                        }


                        if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
                        {
                            image1.Visible = true;
                            image2.Visible = false;
                            image3.Visible = false;
                        }


                        imageUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(image1);
                        imageUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(image2);
                        imageUpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(image3);


                        //Create animation for update panel
                        upAnimator = new UpdatePanelAnimationExtender();
                        upAnimator.ID = "upAnimator";
                        upAnimator.TargetControlID = imageUpdatePanel.ID;
                        const string xml = "<OnUpdating>" +
                            "<Parallel duration=\".25\" Fps=\"30\">" +
                            "<FadeOut AnimationTarget=\"updateContainer\" minimumOpacity=\".2\" />" +
                            "</OnUpdating>" +
                            "<OnUpdated>" +
                            "<FadeIn AnimationTarget=\"updateContainer\" minimumOpacity=\".2\" />" +
                            "</OnUpdated>";

                        Animation.Parse(xml, upAnimator);
                        this.Controls.Add(upAnimator);

                        Button b1 = new Button();
                        b1.ID = "b1i";
                        b1.Click += new EventHandler(b1_Click);
                        b1.Text = "Image 1";


                        Button b2 = new Button();
                        b2.ID = "b2i";
                        b2.Click += new EventHandler(b2_Click);
                        b2.Text = "Image 2";


                        Button b3 = new Button();
                        b3.ID = "b3i";
                        b3.Click += new EventHandler(b3_Click);
                        b3.Text = "Image 3";

                        this.Controls.Add(b1);
                        this.Controls.Add(b2);
                        this.Controls.Add(b3);

                        AsyncPostBackTrigger tr1 = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                        tr1.ControlID = b1.ID;
                        //tr1.EventName = "Click";
                        imageUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(tr1);


                        AsyncPostBackTrigger tr2 = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                        tr2.ControlID = b2.ID;
                        //tr2.EventName = "Click";
                        imageUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(tr2);


                        AsyncPostBackTrigger tr3 = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                        tr3.ControlID = b3.ID;
                        //tr3.EventName = "Click";
                        imageUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(tr3);


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    HandleException(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            image1.Visible = true;
            image2.Visible = false;
            image3.Visible = false;
        }
        void b2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            image1.Visible = false;
            image2.Visible = true;
            image3.Visible = false;
        }
        void b3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            image1.Visible = false;
            image2.Visible = false;
            image3.Visible = true;
        }
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);

        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {


            base.Render(writer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures that the CreateChildControls() is called before events.
        /// Use CreateChildControls() to create your controls.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_error)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.OnLoad(e);
                    this.EnsureChildControls();

                    // Your code here...
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    HandleException(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clear all child controls and add an error message for display.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ex"></param>
        private void HandleException(Exception ex)
        {
            this._error = true;
            this.Controls.Clear();
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ex.Message));
        }
    } }
```

Comment: I know this isn't the best way to achieve what i want to do either..Ideally I want to use jQuery to animate through the images client-side to completely avoid the need to post back to the server to change the image. My problem is I don't know how to insert jQuery into a MOSS 2007 web part and then reference the images / animate them.. Hmm...

Comment: You'll want to look at SPServices pluging for jQuery to answer your comment. We have a part that does exactly this: read from a list to get the top stories for the site and animate on a delay timer between them. I'm sure there are web examples of this; I doubt the guy on the team who built it did it all from scratch.

Comment: Also, the Page cannot be null is most likely coming from the scriptmanager call. You might have to delay until the prerender to have a real Page instance. CreateChildControls is called in a lot of places and, maybe for some reason, Page isn't a real object one of the times it's being called. >> if (ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page) == null)

Comment: Thanks Erik, I'll try placing the toolkit in OnPreRender just to see if it fixes the problem and then look at SPServices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18091/content-rotator-for-sharepoint-lists) though being asked in the context of SP 2010, it's still directly applicable [given the solution](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Creating-your-own-Content-Slider-for-SharePoint.aspx).

We have a CQWP on our MOSS farm that does essentially the same thing: reads items from a list using jQuery and the SPServices plugin and animates slider changes. The most difficult part of the process is actually tweaking the look, if I remember correctly. Once you have the right pieces, putting it together is a snap.

Comment: That solution does look good but I need to be able to trigger the animation by clicking on a button as opposed to having it automatically scrolling. I'm sure I can tweak it somehow...

Comment: Quite easily. Do you have experience with jQuery? Rather than binding to a timeout, you can bind on button click. Check out the docs - very easy to use library and SPServices makes integration with SharePoint easy. It just wraps the SharePoint web services that are already exposed so it's not doing anything 'tricky.'

Comment: Yep after a little investigation I see the jShowOff plugin already comes with slide controls as part of it's design. I'll just adjust where they are positioned on the page and style to suit my requirements. Otherwise I will do as you have suggested and bind to other images/onclick. Thanks Erik!